# Why can't I set <v-app-bar> height to auto?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Very simple code.

```
<div>

  <v-app-bar
    app
    flat
  >
    <v-app-bar-title>
      Page Title
    </v-app-bar-title>
  </v-app-bar>

  <v-container fluid>
    <v-card
      height="400"
      outlined
      flat
    >
      <v-card-title>
        Card Title
      </v-card-title>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>

</div>
```

[image]

Everything works as expected, but if I add `height="auto"` to my `<v-app-bar>` this happens.

[image]

Looks like `<v-main>` is no more calculated correctly. How can I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question "***why** you can't set `<v-app-bar>` height to auto*" you need to deep dive into Vuetify sources.

So, basically `<v-app-bar>` is the extension of `<v-toolbar>` component. [Looking at the sources](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VToolbar/VToolbar.ts), we can find that height style prop is calculated by this code:

```ts
genContent () {
  return this.$createElement('div', {
    staticClass: 'v-toolbar__content',
    style: {
      height: convertToUnit(this.computedContentHeight),
    },
  }, getSlot(this))
},
```

We are interested in how `this.computedContentHeight` calculates. Look at this code:

```ts
computedContentHeight (): number {
  if (this.height) return parseInt(this.height)
  if (this.isProminent && this.dense) return 96
  if (this.isProminent && this.short) return 112
  if (this.isProminent) return 128
  if (this.dense) return 48
  if (this.short || this.$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown) return 56
  return 64
},
```

The answer is: every time when you pass some string into `height` prop, Vuetify tries to convert it into integer value. You are trying to pass `auto` value, but `parseInt("auto")` is `NaN`. That's why you can't pass this value. I think, it is not explained well in Vuetify docs.

If you are **really** want to set `height:auto`, you can set `style="height: auto"` for your `<v-app-bar>` component. But, as [@yoduh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6225326) already said, possibly it is not what you want.

Comment: I assume there's no workaround to this, Am I right?

Comment: @PyKKe, you didn't mention in your question what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Well, I want to use an auto height <v-app-bar> without losing proper <v-main> calculation.

Comment: @PyKKe, I still don't understand what are you trying to achieve. If you just want to place `height: auto` into your `<v-app-bar>` component - it is possible, use style tag. For me it does nothing, maybe it will do something in your template. If you are trying to create some auto-resizable template - the answer is no, you can't do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

With height="auto", v-main no longer knows how much padding to use to offset your page content from the app-bar because it can't know what height=auto will end up being in pixels ahead of time, so v-main ends up at the top of the viewport behind the app-bar.  To avoid the issue, just don't use height="auto".  If you want a smaller app-bar, vuetify provides the `dense` prop that you can use, or you can always specify a specific height pixel value

Comment: So my assumption was correct. I assume there's no workaround to this, Am I right?